# SharePoint Online Pre-Pend Number column with PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, modern-experience, pnp-powershell, number

Through the UI its possible to pre-pend a number column - See screenshot below:

[image]

How can this pre-pended text be changed or added with PowerShell?

Comment: Hi, does below solution help you in any way? If yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirements, you have to set below properties for the number column:

- Unit='Custom'
- CustomUnitName='ABC-SITE-Ref'
- CustomUnitOnRight='FALSE'

**Example**:

Try using this PnP PowerShell code:

```
#Initialize Variables
$SiteURL = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/xyz"
$ListName= "Employees"
 
#Connect to site using PnP PowerShell
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)
 
#Define XML schema for Number field
$FieldXML= "<Field Unit='Custom' CustomUnitName='ABC-SITE-Ref' CustomUnitOnRight='FALSE' CommaSeparator='TRUE' DisplayName='NumberCol' Format='Dropdown' IsModern='TRUE' Name='NumberCol' Percentage='FALSE' Title='NumberCol' Type='Number'></Field>"
 
#Add number field to list using XML
Add-PnPFieldFromXml -FieldXml $FieldXML -List $ListName
```